# Is it coincidence that Microsoft's new browser name matches the X-UA-Compatible value?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

The normal way to specify to IE to use the latest features rather than compatibility mode is:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Is this where the name *Edge* is derived from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/29/8511169/microsoft-edge-official-name-internet-explorer-upgrade) page,

> The Edge naming won’t surprise many as it’s the same moniker given to the new rendering engine (EdgeHTML)

So that made me look up "EdgeHTML". Up [until the end of 2014](https://www.google.com/search?q=EdgeHTML&num=100&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2001%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2014&tbm=), the only mention is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-interoperability.aspx), where "Edge" is mentioned in the context **"Living on the edge"**. It also specifies, as does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML), that "Edge" will

> also drops support for the X-UA-Compatible header

which means Microsoft Edge actually doesn't care about that tag.

On the other hand, the `"IE=edge"` tag is much older than that, with the first [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd835379.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) I could find dating back to mid-2009 when IE 8 was "living on the edge".

Without an answer from the people actually involved in naming, we can only speculate, but I'd like to think the naming was not *derived* from the compatibility header, but had the same "source", referencing the "Living on the edge".

Also, it might reference the fact that Microsoft's browser is "on the edge" of becoming irrelevant. :-)